# where clause in COUNT function and joining two queries

Tags: mysql

I have a table that I am trying to count the number of course passed, and also list the modules passed as well.

The first problem I am having is what to put in the where variable, so that its not specific to a customer(I can use the query below for a particular customer and a particular course)but I will like a generic query where the result will be distinct in terms of user and course like the one below

```
SELECT FirstName
    ,LastName
    ,CourseTitle
    ,Noofmodules
    ,count(Coursecompleted) AS modulescompleted
FROM EStudentsprogress
WHERE Coursecompleted = '1'
    AND EmailAddress = 'scascsc@e.co.uk'
    AND CourseTitle = 'Microsoft MOS 2010 EXCEL'
GROUP BY FirstName
    ,LastName
    ,CourseTitle
    ,Noofmodules
```

How can I make it list the result as above, whereby I don't specify the email address or course title(trying to get the result for all the clients )

Also I have a query that list the courses that is passed by the customer, I will like the column with the list of courses passed be added to the result above, but as a column for each course.

```
SELECT FirstName
    ,LastName
    ,CourseTitle
    ,EmailAddress
    ,CourseModule AS coursepassed
FROM EStudentsprogress
WHERE coursecompleted = 1
```

Cheers

Comment: Could you add an example of what you want to see for your second query?

Comment: Lets say the microsoft course has 6 modules( module 1, module 2.e.t.c) and the customer passes only module 1 and module 4. I will like the first table to have columns attached to the result for the customer as course passed and the content will be module 1, another column course passed and the column will be module 4.

Comment: Just select all passed courses and count them on php side per user

Comment: i used is not null for the first query and it seems to work, 

    select FirstName,LastName,CourseTitle,Noofmodules, count (Coursecompleted) as modulescompleted from EStudentsprogress where Coursecompleted = '1'and EmailAddress IS NOT NULL
    and CourseTitle IS NOT NULL Group by FirstName, LastName, CourseTitle, Noofmodules ;


but i still have to verify it for each user now to be sure its ok

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just add the email address and course title fields to the select fields and the GROUP BY clause.

Also you can use GROUP_CONCAT to bring back a field containing all the course modules.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT FirstName, 
        LastName, 
        CourseTitle, 
        Noofmodules, 
        EmailAddress, 
        CourseTitlecount, 
        COUNT(Coursecompleted) as modulescompleted,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CourseModule) as modulescompletednames 
FROM EStudentsprogress 
WHERE Coursecompleted = '1'
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, CourseTitle, Noofmodules, EmailAddress, CourseTitlecount ;
```

Comment: i am having incorrect syntax near the keyword FROM.  i am using tsql

Comment: replace the double open bracket after `GROUP_CONCAT` with a single open bracket